# Large number of crawl retries

Tags: 2013, search, crawling

A couple weeks ago, we installed the March 2015 CU to our SharePoint farm. Since then, we've been getting a large number of crawl retries when the crawl engine attempts to crawl our other intranet content. Only thing I'm seeing in the ULS logs are a high number of items like the following:

> ProcessStream failed. Error code 0x80070070, URL http://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.xxx  [fltrdaemon.cxx:4328]  search\native\mssdmn\fltrdaemon.cxx

We've also had the search index become corrupt a couple times, requiring us to do an index reset and re-crawl. Anyone have any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of searching through the ULS logs, I found some entries indicating that the index storage was running out of disk space.

I increased the size of the disk, and that seems to have resolved the issues.